# What am I dong wrong in this formula

Tags: excel

I'm using the formula below to try to calculate a value from a sheet called DATA and put the answer in another. I am using a cell content value (10122) provided by the `INDIRECT` part of the formula
`D6` is a numeric value `D5` is a date. can anyone see whats wrong?

```
=SUMIFS(DATA!E3:INDIRECT("DATA!F3:F"&D6),DATA!F3:INDIRECT("DATA!F3:F"&D6),"Mobile telephone - fm1",INDIRECT("DATA!F3:F"&D6),"INDIRECT("DATA!I3:F"&D5)")
```

Comment: To what precisely are those INDIRECT constructions supposed to resolve? For example, to what range is DATA!E3:INDIRECT("DATA!F3:F"&D6) supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: D6 is the cell that contains the value 10122 (ie. the last row of the records in the DATA sheet) I want to use F3: F10122

Comment: But then why are you also including the portion beginning with E3? Altogether that will then make E3:F3:F10122, which, although syntactically valid, is actually equivalent to the two-column range E3:F10122, not the single-column range F3:F10122.

Comment: had another look an made ammendments

Comment: What's more, SUMIF(S)/COUNTIF(S) are examples of functions with which no detriment to calculation performance is suffered if entire columns are referenced, so it's really not at all necessary to create reduced, dynamic ranges. True, that practice IS necessary with the majority of other functions, e.g. SUMPRODUCT, though this is one of the many strengths of SUMIF(S)/COUNTIF(S).

Comment: =SUMIFS(DATA!$E$3:DATA!$E$10122,DATA!$F$3:DATA!$F$10122,"National Geographic",DATA!$I$3:DATA!$I$10122,"30/09/2015")  -- I want to change the date, E10122, F10122, I10122 cell value to look at 2 cells with a date and numeric value

Comment: Re my last comment, unless of course you specifically want to exclude certain rows within those ranges, of course.

Comment: @XORLX make your comment an answer, along with the the correct way to do the indirect.  It will help with future searches.

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIFS(DATA!$E$3:DATA!$E$10122,DATA!$F$3:DATA!$F$10122,"National Geographic",DATA!$I$3:DATA!$I$10122,"30/09/2015") -- I want to change the date, E10122, F10122, I10122 cell value to look at 2 cells with a date and numeric value

Comment: I meant for XOR LX to put his comment as an answer. If you are giving more clarification you should put it in the original post not as an answer.